# MongoDB aggregation to compare a property value of same collection, but every adjacent documents for a given time range

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The MongoDB collection I worked here is **`Generators`**
There are documents in this below format,

```
_id: 64b7561db1fac11016dccfdb
TS: "1689736733498"
SID: "A005"
GEN:  Array
 0:Object
GID: 1
GVT: 1
GTS: 1689735100493938200
GFL: 0.65
__v: 0
```

This document has a `GEN`array. It has a single object. In that object it has `GID, GVT, GTS` and `GFL` values. Here I need to compare each document for same `SID` value for a given `TS`(timestamp as a epoch) range. For this purpose I sorted these documents in descending order for `TS`. `GFL` value is the **fuel level**. Let's say there are 100 documents, then compare each from latest to old using `TS` value. Need to compare the adjacent two documents(**doc1** and **doc2** respectively). The **doc1** is latest document and **doc2** is previous document. If `GFL latest < GFL previous`, then get the difference of two `GFL` values. Then compare the the **doc2** with next previous doc (**doc3**). Revise the same procedure and if above mentioned condition is true, then add the difference of `GFL` here with previously taken difference value. Need to do this for all documents matched. Here are the stages I followed. But, I was stuck.

**stage 1 ($sort) :**

```
{
  SID: 1,
  TS: -1,
}
```

**stage 2 ($match):**

```
{
  SID: "A005",
  TS: {
    $gte: "1689742109823",
    $lte: "1689744959849",
  },
}
```

**stage 3 ($group):**

```
{
  _id: "$SID",
  data: {
    $push: "$$ROOT",
  },
}
```

Then the all selected documents for required time range are pushed as objects into a single document. This document format is as follows;

```
_id:"A005"
data: Array
0:Object
1:Object
2:Object...etc
```

**Stage 4 ($unwind):**

```
{
  path: "$data",
  includeArrayIndex: "index",
  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
}
```

In this phase unwind the all documents with an `index` value from `0`. The result format is as follows;

```
_id: "A005"
data: Object
index: 0

_id: "A005"
data: Object
index: 1

_id: "A005"
data: Object
index: 2
```

Now, I want to compare `GFL` value of `index:1` document with `index:2` document. Then compare `index:2` and `index:3`. The `GFL` value is inside the data object as below. But I am stuck at taking these adjacent documents and compare them with condition above mentioned and if condition is true get the difference of `GFL`. Need to do this for the all documents I have taken from **stage 4** and return the sum of that all differences. Anyone can suggest me how handle this further to get the result successfully?

```
_id: 64b77640c1889f1015c9e10d
TS: "1689744959849"
SID: "A005"
GEN: Array
__v: 0
```

Comment: I think you can use `$setWindowFields` to do this (no need for your current third and fourth stages probably)

Comment: Actually I am not aware of It. I will try it.

Comment: Also, i would like to give a try to continue where I was stuck.